# ListAdapter (List<item>, Context) in ListAdapter cannot be applied to (List<item>)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-context

I am trying to get Items from API using retrofit2, but i am get this error "ListAdapter (List, Context) in ListAdapter cannot be applied to (List)"

Error is on onResponse method.

Here is the code.

Activity

```
Call<ListData> listDataCall = youTubeApi.getlists(channelId, apiKey);
    listDataCall.enqueue(new Callback<ListData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PlaylistData> call, Response<PlaylistData> response) {
            int statusCode = response.code();
            ListData listData = response.body();
            Log.d("list", "onResponse: " + statusCode);
            ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(listData.getListItems()); //Error is here
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PlaylistData> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Playlist", "onResponse: " + t.getMessage());

        }
    });
```

Adapter

```
private final Context context;
private List<ListItem> myPlayList; 
public ListAdapter(List<ListItem> cPlaylist, Context _context) {
    myPlayList = cPlaylist;
    context = _context;
}
```

Comment: ListAdapter  please pass context as second parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "ListAdapter (List, Context) in ListAdapter cannot be applied to
>   (List)"

**Parameter Missing .**

You should pass **CurrentActivity Name** as **2nd Parameter** .

```
 ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(listData.getListItems(),Your_Current_Activity_Name.this);
```